# problem to connect to Oracle from my C# WinForm program

Tags: c#, oracle

i try to connect to Oracle 11.2.0 64bit from my C# program

and i get this error:

> Attempt to load Oracle client
>   libraries threw
>   BadImagFormatException. This problem
>   will occur when running in 64 bit mode
>   with the 32 bit Oracle client
>   components installed.

my code for connect to Oracle

```
Conect = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + IP + ")(PORT=" + PORT + ")))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=" + Server + ")));User Id=" + UID + ";Password=" + PASS + ";";

Conn = new OracleConnection(Conect); 
Conn.Open();
```

and my program compile on X86 (for working on 64 bit)

what i need to download or change in my C# program ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You should post your code, or we can't help you with what to change.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using oracle 32bit client you need to rebuild your app from Any CPU to x86.

Comment: i know this , but this isn't the problem

Comment: Try change Project -> Properties -> Build -> Target CPU to x86 too